# Nethereum invalid sender: eth_sendRawTransaction on polygon chain

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, send, nethereum, matic

```
static async Task SendTx(Wallet wallet, string toAddress, double amountOfCoins)
        {
            var accountFrom = new Account(wallet.GetAccount(0).PrivateKey, 137);
            
                        
            var web3 = new Web3(accountFrom, network);
            var wei = Web3.Convert.ToWei(amountOfCoins);
            decimal amt = 2.99m;
           var tx = await web3.Eth.GetEtherTransferService().TransferEtherAsync(toAddress, amt);
```

Throws an error for `invalid sender: eth_sendRawTransaction`. I create the Wallet in another function. When I try to debug it, the information looks correct. The from and to Addresses look good, I know the wallet has a balance....etc. Is there something special I have to do other than declaringthe chainID(137) when I'm transacting on Polygon network?

Anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, got it. You must set `web3.TransactionManager.UseLegacyAsDefault = true` and skip settings manually gas fee. Enjoy :-)

https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum/issues/750